# competition math references?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

i want to  prepare for  competition math next years I am searching reference and  some book or website about it  What resources are available to prepare me for the competition math?  if anyone had any ideas on what I should study to prepare or if anyone has any references  ( reference about abstract algebra ,linear algebra ,analysis ,complex analysis ,... )that would help me to learn  it would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do more sample competition exams, like the Putnam

Comment: @Danny Cheuk:whats Putnam exam ?

Comment: http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnamindex.shtml

Comment: @Danny Cheuk:humm thanks .its excellent

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php?

Comment: http://www.brilliant.org/

Comment: @Joseph:thanks dear is there any book that classify  competition-math question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few books which have problems (with solutions) relevant for undergraduate problem solving competitions:

- [Putnam and Beyond](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387257659)
- [Problem-Solving Through Problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961712)
- [The IMO Compendium](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441998535)

There are also some books which have all the Putnam problems with solutions and commentary, although I haven't used these so I can't say if they are different from the link posted by Danny Cheuk in the comments. The most recent one is [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088385807X).

Comment: The IMO is not an undergraduate competition.

Comment: @Potato I never claimed it was. In my experience, many IMO problems are more difficult than the 1's and 2's on the Putnam exam, so they make a good source of problems regardless of the age at which the contest is normally taken.

Comment: @Jospeh I'm not so sure. A lot of what appears on the IMO is mostly useless for the Putnam. (Your other two suggestions are excellent, though.)

Answer (score 1):

It is useful if training is competition-specific. For the Putnam, there is a lot available. Googling "Putnam training sessions" and relatives will produce a large amount of material. I particularly like the training material that  William Kahan produced for many years for Berkeley students.